# Unable to cast ltree JPARepository

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

**Native query :**

```
1. SELECT * from test where path <@ 'a.b.c' and path <> 'a.b.c';
2. SELECT * FROM test WHERE path ~ '*.b.c.*{1}'
```

**JPA:**

```
@Query(value = "select * from test where path <@ 'a.b.c' and path <> 'a.b.c'", nativeQuery = true)
List<Test> getAllPath(@Param("pathToSearch") String pathToSearch);
```

I wanna to replace a.b.c with **pathToSearch** param

**Error:**

```
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: operator does not exist: ltree <@ character varying
  Hint: No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

Answer (score 1):

It works

```
@Query(value = "SELECT * FROM test WHERE path <@ CAST(:pathToSearch AS ltree) and path <> CAST(:pathToSearch AS ltree)", nativeQuery = true)
```